# App operations ( install,un-install,upgrades) using powershell for Sharepoint Online office 365

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, upgrade

We are currently building our Intranet site in Office 365 SharePoint Online using App Model.We are using SharePoint Hosted Apps with Client Object Model.The data for the App is from a Custom list which sit's inside the App.So its a Self-contained App.

The challenge we are facing currently facing is every time we upgrade an App,the data is being lost.I wanted to know if there are Powershell cmdlets which allows you to do App operations like install,un-install,upgrade using Powershell.This would save lot of time.

I know Powershell supports App Upgrades for On-premise version but not sure about Online version.

Any new ways to upgrade an App with out losing the data ?

Comment: Are you incrementing the version number when you publish the app? That will prevent you from losing data. The SharePoint Online Management Shell consists of 30 cmdlets, none of which are useful for what you ask.  However, you may be able to do something with csom.  I've just started looking into this, with this blog as a guide:  http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html  Not sure if it will be useful for you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While developing the apps in development environment you can use SPFastDeploy tool to make the updates with out redeploying everything. In case of production you can try to use the UpgradedEventEndpoint web service to preserve the data.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/549fe831-4113-480e-ad78-0e9d8d8c7d09/how-to-upgrade-apps-without-loosing-data

I hope this helps.